# How do I fix the placement of these bones?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, pose-mode

I'm really confused with the placement of some of the bones in my rig. The controller bones for the fingers (the ones in green) keep moving whenever I jump into Pose Mode from Edit Mode. The same happens to the C_look_target too; it appears behind the model. How can I fix this so they appear in the same place in both modes?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's because your **D_Hand_L** bone has a *Copy Rotation* constraint with a *Space* > **World Space <-> World Space** while it should be **Local Space <-> Local Space**. It was dependent of the rotation of the other bone in the Global Space so it was rotating a bit as soon as you entered in *Pose* mode.

Comment: Okay, that's helped somewhat. Though now I'm having issues with my controller bones for the fingers. In the reference model I'm trying to replicate, the deform bones (in red) shouldn't be moving, only the green controller bone. None of the transforms are locked for the reference model either. However, with my deform bones, they move parts of the finger, but the control bone doesn't do anything, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: So it's another question